# Redondear decimal hacia arriba en Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Tengo un numero de decimal 1.1 o 1.2 o  1.6 o 1.9 lo que quiero es aproximar cualquiera de estos números a 2.

Es decir tengo un 1.1. ¿Cómo lo aproximo a 2? Por medio de `int()` todos los aproxima a 1, lo mismo si tengo 3.4 o un 3.1 o 3.8 los aproxima a 3. ¿Cómo aproximar a 4 y así para otros números?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Puedes utilizar la función `ceil` del módulo `math` (que *redondea* hacia **arriba**) o la función `floor` (que *redondea* hacia **abajo**)

```
import math
math.ceil(1.1)
math.ceil(1.2)
math.ceil(1.6)
math.ceil(1.9)
```

**Salida:**

```
2
2
2
2
```

Para más información:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html

Comment: Esto es una buena solución. Pero podría decirse que es la más rápida si se va a ejecutar varias veces? O existe otra manera de hacerlo?

Comment: Math de Python es un wrapper sobre la librería Cmath, así que no dudo de que es rápida. ¿La más rápida? Esa es una afirmación muy fuerte para hacer en programación, pero podes hacer la prueba por tu cuenta y controlar el tiempo programáticamente para saber cuanto tarda. La solución "casera" más simple que se me ocurre es quitarle al float su parte decimal, y sumarle 1, podes implementar eso y comparar tiempos.

Answer (score 0):

Podés agregarle `0.5` a la variable que deseas redondear hacia arriba
no importa que valor sea si es `4.9` pasará a ser `5.4` y con la función `round()` se redondea al `5`.

**Ejemplo:**

```py
a =  1.2 + 0.5
print(round(a))
```

**Salida:**

```
2
```

Comment: Esta solución es eficaz, pero poco eficiente. Si vas a llamar a una función, puedes llamar a la función ceil y te ahorras tener que hacer la asignación. Un saludo.

Answer (score -1):

Yo tuve el mismo problema y lo resolví de la siguiente forma.
Suponiendo que x sea un número cualquiera que deseas redondear hacia arriba, así:

```
def redondeo_arriba(x):    
    x = int(x) + 1
    print(x)
```

Así, si la Entrada es:

```
redondeo_arriba(1.1)
redondeo_arriba(1.6)
```

La Salida sería:

```
'2'
'2'
```

Comment: `redondeo_arriba(1.0)` arroja resultado `2`.